# For what values of $r$ does the function $y = e^{rx}$ satisfy the differential equation $y'' − 4y' + y = 0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I took $y'' − 4y' + y = 0$ and substituted $e^{rx}$ for $y$ but then I just get $e^{rx}=0$ and that's where I'm stuck, if that's even along the correct line of thought.

For what values of $r$ does the function $y = e^{rx}$ satisfy the differential equation $y'' − 4y' + y = 0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you plug in $y = e^{rx}$ into the equation as you suggested, you get
$$r^2e^{rx} - 4re^{rx} + e^{rx} = 0,$$
and since $e^{rx}$ is never zero, you can divide to get an equation in $r$.

Comment: $y' = re^{rx}$... and then taking the derivative again should give the result.